# Extract Information from .plist without Loading the Whole File?

Tags: objective-c, deserialization, plist, darwin

I am writing a Bluetooth based application with components in both OS X and iOS. I want to be able to show the name of the manufacturer of a device upon discovery. The Bluetooth SIG assigned numbers page specifies 819 vendor names, each associated with a unique 32 bit identifier.

In order to save RAM I figured that instead of compiling all those key-value pairs into my executable, I would use a plist file in my bundle. This way, I thought, this large dictionary would reside quietly on the disk instead of in memory. I thought I would be able to extract data when needed and cast a lighter footprint.

The problem is I've realized that this method alone will hurt performance. I've found no way to access the information in the plist except the normal way of calling

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"company-identifiers" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

which goes through the trouble of reading the entire file into a huge dictionary object every time any information from the file is needed.

So really what I'm asking is **how do I extract a single key-value pair from a plist without deserializing the whole file?**

Comment: Sounds like a job for a relational database (CoreData/sqlite).

Comment: @trojanfoe Would that really make sense within a single, local application tho?

Comment: It's all a trade-off.  Depends how much you care about memory footprint and performance.  I probably wouldn't be bothered for just this one function, however.

Comment: @trojanfoe Nor would I, but there are many, many more assigned numbers to come. Literally megabytes of them.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for the tip to look at CoreData. I've never used it and hadn't thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to retrieve specific data without loading the entire file it is stored in requires information on where exactly that data is stored such as an offset and length... so you end up with another file, and one that is in some respects similar to an index file, which again is something that databases generally have. So maybe a database would be in order.

CoreData absolutely makes sense in many cases because is intended to be used for local data storage by your app. It's optimized to minimize memory usage and is fast for the most part.

Of course, where it makes sense for your specific case depends how much data you have. Maybe splitting things into multiple plists would be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/) which parses XML documents in an event-driven manner. So, you will have to keep track of the state in order to know when you have received the element/attribute you are looking for.

That said I think you won't receive the benefits you are aiming for. If the element you are looking for is near the top of the file you will get the data pretty quick but if it's the last item in the document then you'll still end up waiting until the entire file has been read. Also, how many times do you need to lookup another item? If it's more than once then you'll end up re-scanning the file again and again negating any short-term gains.

I would suggest using CoreData for tasks where you need to retrieve indexed data in an efficient manor.